# Replace subquery with variable SQL Server

Tags: sql, variables, sql-server-2008-r2, subquery

I have multiple delete statements to run on SQL Server 2008 R2

```
DELETE FROM A WHERE A_id in (SELECT B_id FROM B WHERE B_name = 'Target')
DELETE FROM B WHERE B_id in (SELECT B_id FROM B WHERE B_name = 'Target')
DELETE FROM C WHERE C_id in (SELECT B_id FROM B WHERE B_name = 'Target')
DELETE FROM D WHERE D_id in (SELECT B_id FROM B WHERE B_name = 'Target')
```

Is there a way that I can use a variable to replace the repetitive subquery? Is there such a variable type to hold the subquery or its results?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have any relationships between these tables?

Comment: I don't see any other way than using dynamic SQL to shorten this.

Answer (score 0):

Table variable to hold the IDs to delete...

```
Declare @BIDs Table
(
  B_Id Int Not Null
)

Insert Into @BIDs (B_Id)
SELECT B_Id FROM B WHERE B_Name = 'Target'

DELETE FROM A WHERE A_id in (SELECT B_id FROM @BIDs)
DELETE FROM B WHERE B_id in (SELECT B_id FROM @BIDs)
DELETE FROM C WHERE C_id in (SELECT B_id FROM @BIDs)
DELETE FROM D WHERE D_id in (SELECT B_id FROM @BIDs)
```

Comment: While true, that doesn't shorten the code nor does it make it better in any way...

Comment: There is probably not much that can be done here but I think it is slightly better. This refactor removes the violation of DRY and possibly little more efficient when the SQL server would have to query the table B once vs each time for every delete. Again, depending upon the number of rows in table B, indexes on column B_name, that efficiency might not be viable/needed. For me, the most important reason would be to not have to repeat the same query for each delete - DRY.